# MacVim - keyboard shortcut to change tab left

Tags: vim

What is the command for changing to the tab to the left? `gt` is changing to the right, but I can't find the command for going the other way.

Thanks

Comment: check out [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/382060/macvim-switch-tab-shortcut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's `gT`. The logic is the same as with `fF`, `tT` or `oO`.